# Select from a result of another select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select results from the result of another select but I am getting an error. Below is the sql query.

```
select reference,date, 
       bdx_name,
       bdx_id,
       description,
       amount,
       cumulativetotal 
  from (select reference,
               date,
               bdx_name,
               bdx_id,
               description,
               amount,
               SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY bdx_id order by date) AS cumulativetotal
          from transaction_running_balance
         where bdx_id = '33')
 where date(date) = '2021-03-01';
```

Comment: And the error you get is?

Comment: I guess the problem is the column name date, because it is a reserved word you have to escape it

Comment: @Jens, MySQL doesn't seem to have `date` as reserved. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words.

Comment: @jarlh the mysql documentation says something else https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Jens, Note the "_Reserved keywords are marked with (R)._". `date` has no (R), i.e. non-reserved keyword. A quick test: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85599c9afa6c85f1fa501c4fa9dc7fbf

Comment: this is the error message.
[2021-05-17 10:45:22] [42000][1064] (conn=232) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where date(date) = '2021-03-01'' at line 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using MariaDB 10.2, which is the first version to accept window functions, have a look at the [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=74f613061526eb6fcd97c5e967182cbb) I just prepared with random data. Take into account that for DDL purposes, I changed the `date` column name to `date_`.

You either create a CTE to control the data, which to me is easier to read than a nested SELECT statement:

```
with temp_table as (
  select 
    reference, 
    date_, 
    bdx_name, 
    bdx_id, 
    description, 
    amount, 
    SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY bdx_id ORDER BY date_) AS cumulativetotal
  from transaction_running_balance
  where bdx_id = 33
 )
 select * from temp_table where date(date_) = '2021-03-01';
```

Or give a name to the nested query you just made at the end of it after closing parentheses:

```
select reference,
       date_, 
       bdx_name,
       bdx_id,
       description,
       amount,
       cumulativetotal 
  from (select reference,
               date_,
               bdx_name,
               bdx_id,
               description,
               amount,
               SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY bdx_id order by date_) AS cumulativetotal
          from transaction_running_balance
         where bdx_id = 33) AS nested_query
 where date(date_) = '2021-03-01';
```

Same result for both cases :)

Comment: great @MapfundeVenon ! feel free to upvote the solution, so other people will be able to trust it :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In sql server you need to name table which you create in sub-query.

```
select reference,date, 
       bdx_name,
       bdx_id,
       description,
       amount,
       cumulativetotal 
  from (select reference,
               date,
               bdx_name,
               bdx_id,
               description,
               amount,
               SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY bdx_id order by date) AS cumulativetotal
          from transaction_running_balance
         where bdx_id = '33') as TEMP
 where date(date) = '2021-03-01';
```

Comment: This is mariadb

Comment: MariaDB also this behavior.